# Set column cell value as formula in dynamic range Maatwebsite/Excel 2.1.0

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm stumped here and hoping someone out there has an answer or can point me in the right direction!

Using: ***Laravel 5.7*** | ***Maatwebsite/Excel 2.1.0***

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I want to insert a basic formula into a column across a dynamic number of rows when exporting. I know I can use

```
$sheet->setCellValue('H2','=SUM(G2*F2)');
```

to set a specific cell value. I'm *assuming* the answer lies [somewhere here](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/export/cells.html)

```
$sheet->cells('H2:H'.$numRows, function($cells) {

    // manipulate the range of cells

});
```

but we all know what happens when you assume something. Does anyone have any insight on this at all? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over each cell in the range that you have found and set it's value to the formula that you want.

```
$sheet->cells('H2:H'.$numRows, function($cells) {

     foreach($cells as $cell) {
         $cell->setValue('=SUM(G2*F2)');
     }

});
```

Or if you have custom formula for some cells in the range based on the documentation for PhpSpreadSheet which Maatwebsite uses, you can see how to set range of cells [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/#setting-a-range-of-cells-from-an-array) from an array.

So for your case you can build a 1-d array and place it as columns like this:

```
$rowArray = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= $numOfRows; $i++) {
    $rowArray[] = '=SUM(G2*F2)'; // customize the formula if needed for specific row
}

$columnArray = array_chunk($rowArray, 1);
$sheet->fromArray(
        $columnArray,   // The data to set
        NULL,           // Array values with this value will not be set
        'H2'            // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
                        // we want to set these values (default is A1)
);
```

Comment: Ah, the missing link. Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it.. been stuck on this for a bit now.

Answer (score 4):

This may help you

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;


Class ExportData implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents

public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
            $event->sheet->setCellValue('E'. ($event->sheet->getHighestRow()+1), '=SUM(E2:E'.$event->sheet->getHighestRow().')');
        }
    ];
}

...
"Your code to export"
...

"Note:
  1.in my case the data I want to get the SUM is in "E" Column you can change it as you want

  2.You only need to implement "WithEvents" and  use "AfterSheet" other things that I implemented is for other purposes
"
```